# Add border to 2 sides of CSS triangle?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

Result:

[image: Arrow]

Is there any way I can produce a 1 pixel border on the two sides of the result? (the non 180 degree ones)?

Thanks

Comment: could you supply a simple image for the border you want?

Comment: A CSS triangle *is* a border, so adding a border to it doesn't make much sense. However, it is possible -- see http://cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100% pure CSS, no... but add an extra div in there and:

HTML

```
<div class="arrow-right">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid black;
}
.arrow-right > div {
    width: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: -60px;
    top: -59px;
    border-top: 59px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 59px solid transparent;
    border-left: 59px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qJJxm/

(replace every instance of `59` with a smaller number to make a wider border - all four should always be the same number)

Comment: Or, as Jose Rui Santos mentioned in his answer, you can use a pseudo class if you're only targeting browsers that support them.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, works perfectly. Prefer this answer for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a border through `before` or `after` pseudo-elements, shifted one pixel to the left.

```
.arrow-right,
.arrow-right:after {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid black;
}

.arrow-right:after {
    border-left-color: green;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: -61px;
    top: -60px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nh63r/

Comment: Maybe missing a border in IE<8 will not be a big of a deal. This is called Graceful Degradation, see http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/  (actually this site renders differently in some browsers)

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos that's true, but that's the developer's decision, so he should be aware of the benefits and costs of either solution.